# jQuery binding events strange behavior

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I have code written in vanilla JavaScript, which at some point during the runtime trigger custom event, which is handled by jQuery with the following piece of code:

```
// Fired on when snapshot is ready
$(document).bind('SnapshotReady', function(e) {
    
    $('#image_container').zoom(); // zoom library
    
    $(document).on('mousestop', '.zoomImg', function() {
        alert('mousestop event occurs');
    })
    
});
```

The problem is that `mousestop` event is never called that way. In the code of zoom library, we have dynamically created element with `.zoomImg` class, and it have the following event handler:

```
$img.on('mousemove', zoom.move);
```

But if I change the above line to:

```
$img
.on('mousemove', zoom.move)
.on('mousestop', function() {
    // strange, but event in other code is fired that way
 });
```

... everything works as excepted, but I don't want to do some calculations twice and I need this event to be triggered within the first piece of code, not in the code of zoom library.

The used library for implementation of `mousestop` event is the following: https://github.com/richardscarrott/jquery-mousestop-event/blob/master/jquery.event.mousestop.js

**Edit:**

```
/* The core code of zoom library */

        img.onload = function () {
            
            var zoom = $.zoom(target, source, img);
  
            function start() {
                
                zoom.init();
                
                // Skip the fade-in for IE8 and lower since it chokes on fading-in
                // and changing position based on mousemovement at the same time.
                $img.stop();
                    
                $img.on('mousemove', zoom.move);

                zoom.automove();
            
            }

            function stop() {
                $img.clearQueue().stop();
            }
                                                        
            $(source).on('mouseleave', stop)
            
            start();
            
        };
```

Comment: Looks like the mouse move event is captured in your zoom library, and it is stopped from being propagated by some piece of code. Could you show us your zoom library? The problem seems to be in there, by the looks of it

Comment: Hmmm, thanks! I've updated the post, there's the core of zooming library now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the snippets you posted, it seems that the problem is in your zoom library code, specifically this bit:

```
        $(source)
        .on('mouseleave', stop)
```

The mousestop plugin checks for mouseenter/mouseleave events, but your zoom library processes mouseleave events too, which seems to create confusion between the two scripts. It's not easy to figure out what's happening without a jsFiddle, though. If that isn't the problem, could you please create a working jsFiddle example?